# What is the average time to compete a small code project?

Tags: text

I was wondering, how much time does it take to finish writing a small working code in python. (600-700 lines)
Is there an average time for a good developper to complete a project based on the complexity? Or it's different for every person?

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, it'd vary from person to person. Depends on skills set/experience as well on how good you're in surfing web to find solutions and integrating them with you code. But then, even if you're beginner in python, don't worry, this amazing language will not let you down anywhere and will get your work done probably quicker than most other languages. Cheers!